# Need separate names for resources that are being managed by a semaphore

Tags: arrays, task, semaphore, naming, ada

I am required to give the name of the resource that my tasks are utilizing, when I execute it. One resource is always in use, and I'm using `SemaUse.K` to pass the value of the private count of the semaphore, the resource is always named `DickDastardly` since he is located in `ArrLCO(0)`. I have not been able, after hours and days of research, to either properly word my search, or locate any useful answers to my particular dilemma.

```
--Tasktypes.adb
WITH Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Calendar, Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;
USE Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Calendar, Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;

Procedure Tasktypes IS
   --definitions
   TYPE RequestType IS (Permission_To_Land, Call_The_Ball, Touch_Down);
   TYPE ShuttleNameType IS (Atlantis, Challenger, Ranger, MeanMachine, HoganHero, Penelope, Jetson, Bullwinkle, PinkPanther, SecretSquirel);
   TYPE LandingControlOfficerName IS (DickDastardly, Muttley, SlagBrothers); --Will I find a way to use these?


   PACKAGE Duration_IO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO(Duration); USE Duration_IO;
   PACKAGE IntIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer); USE IntIO;
   PACKAGE ShuttleNameIO IS NEW ADA.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(ShuttleNameType); USE ShuttleNameIO;
   PACKAGE LandingControlOfficerNameIO IS NEW ADA.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(LandingControlOfficerName);  USE LandingControlOfficerNameIO;

   --For part C we need 2 landing officers, aka available resources, so we initialize start_count to 2
   PROTECTED TYPE Sema(Start_Count: Integer) IS
      ENTRY Wait; --Queue is implied, task serialization like rendezvous
      PROCEDURE Signal; --Re-entrant code, no queue no serialization
      function K return Integer;
      PRIVATE
      Count: Integer := Start_Count;
   END Sema;


   PROTECTED BODY Sema IS
      ENTRY Wait WHEN Count > 0 IS
      BEGIN
         Count := Count - 1;
      END;

      PROCEDURE Signal IS
      BEGIN
         Count := Count + 1;
      END Signal;

   function K return Integer is
  begin  return Count;  end K;
   END Sema;



      RandNum: Generator; --notes on this in lab1


      NameLCO: LandingControlOfficerName;
      NumShuttles: Integer;
      NameShuttles: ShuttleNameType;
      NumLCOS: Integer := 2;
      SemaUse: Sema(NumLCOS);


   TASK TYPE LandingControlOfficer(LCOName: LandingControlOfficerName) IS
      ENTRY Request (InRequestGiven: IN RequestType; InShuttleName: IN ShuttleNameType);
   END LandingControlOfficer;
   Type LCOAccess is Access LandingControlOfficer;


   TYPE LCO_Array IS ARRAY(Integer RANGE <>) OF LCOAccess;
   TASK TYPE Shuttle(ShuttleName: ShuttleNameType);
   TYPE ShuttleAccess IS ACCESS Shuttle;


       TYPE Shuttle_Array IS ARRAY(Integer RANGE <>) OF ShuttleAccess;


      ArrLCO: LCO_Array(0..NumLCOS-1);

   --critical resource where access must be controlled
   TASK BODY LandingControlOfficer IS --Burris wants them both to be task types, unlike lab1.
      --Local Variables
      LCO: LandingControlOfficerName := LCOName;
      RequestGiven: RequestType;
      ShuttleName: ShuttleNameType;


   BEGIN
      LOOP

      ACCEPT Request (inRequestGiven: IN RequestType; inShuttleName: IN ShuttleNameType) DO
         RequestGiven := inRequestGiven;
         ShuttleName := inShuttleName;
      END Request;

      CASE RequestGiven IS
         WHEN Permission_To_Land =>
            DELAY Duration(Random(RandNum) * 10.0);
            --Make Decision
            Put(ShuttleName); PUT(" is Granted Permission To Land by: "); Put(LCO); new_line;
         WHEN Call_The_Ball =>
            DELAY Duration(Random(RandNum) * 15.0);
            --Prepare guidance system
            Put(ShuttleName); Put(" call the ball! "); Put(LCO); New_Line;
         WHEN Touch_Down =>
            Put(ShuttleName); Put(", permission is granted for final approach by: "); Put(LCO); New_Line;
            DELAY Duration(Random(RandNum) * 25.0);
            --Wait for Shuttle to land
      END CASE;
      END LOOP;

   END LandingControlOfficer;



--Task Type body for the Shuttle
   TASK BODY Shuttle IS
      Shuttle: ShuttleNameType := ShuttleName;
      InitiateLandingSequence: Duration;
      LandingComplete: Duration;
   BEGIN
      DECLARE
         Hold: Integer;
      BEGIN

      FOR I IN 1..5 LOOP

            begin
            DELAY Duration(Random(RandNum) * 25.0); --Crew boarding and perform mission

            SemaUse.Wait;
            Put(Shuttle); Put(" entering its critical landing section."); New_Line(2);
            InitiateLandingSequence := Seconds(Clock);


               BEGIN

                  Hold := SemaUse.K;
                  ArrLCO(Hold).Request(Permission_To_Land, Shuttle);
                  ArrLCO(Hold).Request(Call_The_Ball, Shuttle);
                  DELAY Duration(Random(RandNum) * 2.0); --line up shuttle with mother ship
                  ArrLCO(Hold).Request(Touch_Down, Shuttle);

               end;

         LandingComplete := Seconds(Clock);
         Put(Shuttle); Put(" docked in "); Put(LandingComplete - InitiateLandingSequence);Put(" seconds."); New_Line;
         Put(Shuttle); Put(" leaving its critical section. Obtain new crew and start mission."); New_Line(2);
                   end;
            SemaUse.Signal;--NEVER PUT ANYTHING BENEATH THIS> EVER
         END LOOP;
         end;
   END Shuttle;


   BEGIN
   Put("Shuttle operations are authorized.");New_Line;
   --Used as a container by the mother ship to launch and recover shuttles.
   Put("Enter the number of Shuttles you would like: ");New_Line;
   Get(NumShuttles);

   Put("Enter the number of Landing Control Officers: ");New_Line;
   Get(NumLCOS);

   --DivideShuttles := NumShuttles / NumLCOS; --if 10/2, gives 5. If 10/3 gives 3
   --   TempArraySize := NumShuttles;
   --Brainstorming. Can do in psuedo parallel. can use divide shuttles to do for statement.
   --For i in 0 .. NumLCOS-1 loop
     -- TempArraySize := DivideShuttles; --I could end here if only using 2 LCOS

       --  End Loop;

   DECLARE
     ArrShut: Shuttle_Array(0..NumShuttles-1);

      BEGIN
         FOR I IN 0..NumShuttles-1 LOOP

            Put("Enter the names of the Shuttles: ");New_Line;
            Get(NameShuttles);
            ArrShut(I) := new Shuttle(NameShuttles);

         END LOOP;

         FOR I IN 0..NumLCOS-1 LOOP
            Put("Enter the names of the Landing Control Officers: ");New_Line;
            Get(NameLCO);
            ArrLCO(I) := NEW LandingControlOfficer(NameLCO); --Arr 0 and Arr 1 hold the names.
         END LOOP;

END;

END Tasktypes;
```

My redirected input file, `LabC.txt`, consists of the following:

```
10
2
Atlantis
Challenger
Ranger
MeanMachine
HoganHero
Penelope
Jetson
Bullwinkle
PinkPanther
SecretSquirel
DickDastardly
Muttley
```

A sample of my output is:

```
Shuttle operations are authorized.
Enter the number of Shuttles you would like: 
Enter the number of Landing Control Officers: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Shuttles: 
Enter the names of the Landing Control Officers: 
Enter the names of the Landing Control Officers: 
CHALLENGER entering its critical landing section.

MEANMACHINE entering its critical landing section.

MEANMACHINE is Granted Permission To Land by: DICKDASTARDLY
CHALLENGER is Granted Permission To Land by: MUTTLEY
MEANMACHINE call the ball! DICKDASTARDLY
MEANMACHINE docked in          10.860064438 seconds.
MEANMACHINE leaving its critical section. Obtain new crew and start mission.

BULLWINKLE entering its critical landing section.

MEANMACHINE, permission is granted for final approach by: DICKDASTARDLY
CHALLENGER call the ball! MUTTLEY
CHALLENGER, permission is granted for final approach by: MUTTLEY
CHALLENGER docked in          17.099900040 seconds.
CHALLENGER leaving its critical section. Obtain new crew and start mission.

PENELOPE entering its critical landing section.

BULLWINKLE is Granted Permission To Land by: DICKDASTARDLY
PENELOPE is Granted Permission To Land by: DICKDASTARDLY
BULLWINKLE call the ball! DICKDASTARDLY
PENELOPE call the ball! DICKDASTARDLY
BULLWINKLE, permission is granted for final approach by: DICKDASTARDLY
BULLWINKLE docked in          50.230774983 seconds.
BULLWINKLE leaving its critical section. Obtain new crew and start mission.

PINKPANTHER entering its critical landing section.
```

Problem in the output: `Penelope` should be using a resource named `Muttley` not `DickDastardly` as the resource she is utilizing should be blocked by the semaphore. I am pretty sure I have an issue with the way I'm initializing/passing the name of the resource AKA `LandingControlOfficer`.

I greatly appreciate any creative ideas or answers, as I have tried some crazy methods up to this point. Also, if this is not clear, feel free to ask me to respecify.

Comment: I can’t tell what you think of as “resources”, not can I tell, really, what your problem is. Your code isn’t complete, so I can’t run it. What do you _want_ to happen? what _does_ happen? I can’t think your problem is actually thinking of names for your resources?

Comment: Your question is not clear, your example source text is not complete enough to show what is your problem. - Please fix both of these problems.

Comment: I have added all of my code, and it is able to be compiled in ada. I also reworded the question as clearly as I could, including the input, output and an explanation of what the output should be.

Comment: Are you obliged to use an explicit semaphore?  Have you tested your semaphore under controlled conditions?  (Your implementation doesn't look quite like I would expect it.)

Comment: It would be nice if you could use a consistent style throughout your source text. - One option is to follow the style documented in the Ada 95 Style-Guide (see http://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/standards/ada-95-documents/)

Comment: I tested my semaphore by only using one landing control officer and 10 shuttles. The shuttles each took turns utilizing the one available resource. And I'll try to restructure the code in a neater fashion.

Comment: I am required to use the semaphore, and after speaking with a few people, I have been told that my resource needs to "know" its own name. It seems that my semaphore isn't blocking access to two separate resources, but more allowing two shuttles to access and share one resource. I'm not sure if that is true or not, but I have no way to call the Landing Control Officer task if I do not utilize the array it is created in. (And yes, I must have it named and chosen by the user.) I've tried using a LCO:LCOaccess; then LCO.Request(); but that is null and cannot access that which the array holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how many docking stations (runways?) there are. It could be that there are as many docking stations as there are landing control officers, or that there is a limited number (more or less than the current number of LCOs). I *guess* the former, because there's nothing in your description about managing docking stations.

In either case, it seems that each shuttle landing sequence is overseen by a particular landing control officer, so your problem is to allocate an LCO from a pool of available LCOs to a Shuttle at the start of the sequence, and to return that LCO to the pool when the sequence is finished; and the critical resource isn't the individual LCO but the pool of available LCOs.

How to determine *which* LCO? hardly by counting the number of currently available LCOs, which is what your current code does. There's no reason why LCOs should become free in the same order they were allocated (unless there's only one docking station and only one landing sequence at a time); some landings will be shorter than others.

Get rid of your semaphore's `Start_Count`; its `Count` should be initialized to 1. Get rid of `K`.

If you need to, you can tell the LCO which entry it is in the `LCO_Array` when you create it, via a second discriminant:

```
task type LandingControlOfficer
  (LCOName : LandingControlOfficerName;
   Index : Integer) is
```

... but I don't think you do.

Keep an availability indicator with each LCO:

```
type LCOAccess is access LandingControlOfficer;
type LCO_Data is record
   The_LCO : LCOAccess;
   Available : Boolean := True;
end record;
type LCO_Array is array(Integer range <>) of LCO_Data;
```

Have an allocate/release scheme for LCOs:

```
procedure Grab_LCO (Grabbed : out LCOAccess) is
begin
   SemaUse.Wait;
   for J in ArrLCO'Range loop
      if ArrLCO (J).Available then
         ArrLCO (J).Available := False;
         Grabbed := ArrLCO (J).The_LCO;
         SemaUse.Signal;
         return;
      end if;
   end loop;
   Grabbed := null;
   SemaUse.Signal;
end Grab_LCO;

procedure Free_LCO (The_LCO : in out LCOAccess) is
begin
   if The_LCO = null then
      raise Program_Error with "trying to free a null LCO";
   end if;
   SemaUse.Wait;
   for J in ArrLCO'Range loop
      if The_LCO = ArrLCO (J).The_LCO then
         if ArrLCO (J).Available then
            raise Program_Error with "trying to free an already-free LCO";
         end if;
         ArrLCO (J).Available := True;
         The_LCO := null;
         SemaUse.Signal;
         return;
      end if;
   end loop;
   raise Program_Error with "trying to free an unknown LCO";
   --  what happens to SemaUse, then?
end Free_LCO;
```

In task body `Shuttle`, replace `Hold` by

```
Allocated_LCO : LCOAccess;
```

After the mission has been performed,

replace

```
Hold := SemaUse.K;
```

by

```
loop
   Grab_LCO (Grabbed => Allocated_LCO);
   exit when Allocated_LCO /= null;
   Put (Shuttle); Put (" didn't get an LCO yet"); New_Line;
   delay 1.0;
end loop;
```

replace `ArrLCO(Hold)` by `Allocated_LCO` throughout, and replace the final `SemaUse.Signal` by

```
Free_LCO (The_LCO => Allocated_LCO);
```

As a parting thought: it's really quite inappropriate in Ada to use low-level constructs like semaphores to manage resources when you have protected objects. The very clever people (not me!) who create the Ada runtime system use low-level constructs (including semaphores) to implement POs to meet Ada semantics, such as ensuring that the internal semaphores etc are correctly managed when leaving entries/subprograms, even because of an exception; it's just wrong to then use all this clever scaffolding to reconstruct a semaphore, with all its problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that my main issue was that I neglected to utilize my basic data structures in maintain the LCOs.